# How to read image headers with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, cors, fastapi

I have an API I can query to get an image, which has some headers I would like to read.
In the documentation of the API (built with fastAPI), I read that the response body is the image and that the response headers are something like this

```
 Response headers
 access-control-allow-credentials: true 
 content-type: image/png 
 date: Sun,05 Dec 2021 12:08:58 GMT 
 prediction: COVID - 19 
 server: uvicorn 
 transfer-encoding: chunked
```

I would like to acces the prediction header.

Now, when I do the request via axios and React, I ask the response to be of type arraybuffer or blob, so that I can plot it to a webpage. I convert it and then plot it in some way.

```js
   axios.post(Endpoint + 'predict', formData,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                },
                params: {
                    xmin,
                    ymin,
                    xmax,
                    ymax,
                },
                responseType: 'arraybuffer'
            }).then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            let base64ImageString = Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64')
            let srcValue = "data:image/png;base64,"+base64ImageString
            setImage(srcValue)
            console.log(response.headers)
        })
```

Given that the request is for arraybuffer or blob, how should I access the prediction header?

If I try to log the `response.headers` I get this:

```
{
    "content-type": "image/png"
}
```

but I can't access the prediction header.

If some further information are required, I can provide it.
Thanks in advance.

***EDIT***
just add the `expose_headers` parameter to the CORS configuration of the fastAPI code. see docs [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prediction` is not a [CORS-safelisted response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS-safelisted_response_header) so it is not available to client side code unless the API explicitly grants permission with the [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers` response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers).

Change the API to include:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: prediction
```

in its response (in the same bit of code that adds `access-control-allow-credentials`).

Comment: The API should already be exposing all headers. It is written with fastAPI and has this code:
`app.add_middleware( CORSMiddleware, allow_origins=['http://localhost:3000'], allow_credentials=True, allow_methods=["*"], allow_headers=["*"])`, which is what is often suggested when you have cors problems with fastAPI

Comment: @juuso — That sets **allow** headers not **expose** headers. `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` is sets headers the client is allowed to send **to** the server not those it is allowed to read from the response.

Comment: do you know how to do it in fastAPI?

Comment: I think I found the solution here. https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/